# Read json response using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to read below json array.

```
[{"bus_code":"1103030017","bus_name":"Tony\u0027s Sports Bar \u0026 Grill","first_name":"","last_name":"","email":"tonyssports@bellsouth.net","phone":"(770) 552-2233","street_address":"8610 Roswell Rd","city":"Sandy Springs","state":"GA","zip_code":"30350","website":"www.tonyssportsbar.com/","open_hours":"Mon-Fri 11am-2am, Sat-Sun 12pm-2am","features":"Live entertainment, TVs, billiards, Wi-Fi. ","type":"Sports Bar, Restaurant","coords":"33.989659, -84.351690"}]
```

Using this code but not getting success

```
info = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

alert(info.bus_code);
```

but not getting success.

please suggest me any idea.

Comment: send it by your application as a text (download) to ensure have received in correct format or data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
alert(info[0].bus_code);
```

(The object is within an array).

Answer (score 2):

Yours data is already in JSON format. so no need to use `jQuery.parseJSON(data)` and Its an array so use `data[0].bus_code`

```
 var data = [{"bus_code":"1103030017","bus_name":"Tony\u0027s Sports Bar \u0026 Grill","first_name":"","last_name":"","email":"tonyssports@bellsouth.net","phone":"(770) 552-2233","street_address":"8610 Roswell Rd","city":"Sandy Springs","state":"GA","zip_code":"30350","website":"www.tonyssportsbar.com/","open_hours":"Mon-Fri 11am-2am, Sat-Sun 12pm-2am","features":"Live entertainment, TVs, billiards, Wi-Fi. ","type":"Sports Bar, Restaurant","coords":"33.989659, -84.351690"}];
 console.log(data[0].bus_code);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cwMuH/)

As per @Boaz If you input is string then you have to surely use `jQuery.parseJSON`

Comment: The quoted block in the OP is probably a string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
alert(info[0]['bus_code']);

or

alert(info[0].bus_code);
```

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xvybj/)**